# From Two tables i want sum salary

Tags: oracle

I have two tables like emp, customer with two salary columns in both tables

```
emp_sal           cusotmer_sal
--------         -------------
1000               3000
2000               1000
3000               5000
```

I want output combined sum salary in single result like

```
sum(sal)
---------
15000
```

could please comment if anyone knows 
Thank You!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a summation of two subqueries, each one calculating the sum of salary:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(emp_sal) FROM emp) +
    (SELECT SUM(customer_sal) FROM customer)
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select sum(emp_sal) from emptable 
+ 
select sum(cusotmer_sal) from customertable
```